# Check Login Status in every Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written an webApp in ASP.NET MVC4 with C#. I login users with the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true); method.

Now I want to check the login status in every single controller. If no one is logined, the user should be redirectet to the login controller view. I don't want to add this piece of code to every single controller by hand.

Anyone an idea, how to do this?

Comment: use an [authorization] attribute on your controller

Comment: Alternatively, register a global Authorize filter so you can omit the Authorize attribute on each of your controllers. You can still allow anonymous access via the AllowAnonymous attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AuthorizeAttribute] to achieve what you need. For example:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

     [Authorize]
     ActionResult ActionRequiringAuthorization()...
     ....

     [AllowAnonymous] //Will allow both, authenticated and non-authenticated requests
     ActionResult PublicAction() ...
}
```

If the user is no longer authenticated, he'll be redirected to the Login page upon trying to execute any action decorated with the Authorize attribute.

You can decorate the whole Controller to apply the same attribute to all Actions as in:

```
 [Authorize]
 public class AccountController : Controller
```

Comment: You can also check if the user is authenticated using User.Identity.IsAuthenticated inside your controller method. But the best way to control access is with the Attributes @Icarus mentioned. These can also be configured for specific roles like this [Authorize(Roles = "role1,role2")]